# Проблема с Иконками в Toolbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, ftp, pyqt

Не работают иконки, остаются просто кнопки. Не знаю в чем проблема? Прописывал путь полностью. Но все равно, ничего не работает.

Update: Файл `main.py` проекта находится на рабочем столе и папка `FTP` там же.

```
import sys
import ftplib
import easygui 
import pyperclip
import os
from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, Qt                              
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QGraphicsOpacityEffect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication, QMenuBar, qApp
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileSystemModel, QHBoxLayout, QShortcut, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QMenu, QSplitter
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QRect, QFileInfo, Qt, QSize, QDir
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QKeySequence, QImage


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.splitter)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.columns = ['Name', 'Size']

        self.file = self.menuBar().addMenu('&File')
        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), '&Exit', self)
        self.exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.file.addAction(self.exitAction)

        self.server = self.menuBar().addMenu('Server')
        self.connectAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), 'Connect server', self)
        self.connectAction.setStatusTip('Connect server')
        self.connectAction.triggered.connect(self.connect_FTP_server)
        self.connectAction.triggered.connect(self.ftp_lst)
        self.server.addAction(self.connectAction)

        self.disconnectAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), 'Disconnect server', self)
        self.disconnectAction.setStatusTip('Disconnect server')
        self.disconnectAction.triggered.connect(self.disconnect_FTP_server)
        self.server.addAction(self.disconnectAction)

        self.updateAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), 'Update list file', self)
        self.updateShortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence("F5"), self)
        self.updateShortcut.activated.connect(self.ftp_lst)
        self.updateAction.setStatusTip('Update list file')
        self.updateAction.triggered.connect(self.ftp_lst)
        self.server.addAction(self.updateAction)

        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon(':\FTP\disconnect.png'), 'Exit')
        self.exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.disconnect_FTP_server)

        self.refreshAction = QAction(QIcon(':\FTP\refresh.png'), 'Refresh')
        self.refreshAction.setShortcut('F5')
        self.refreshAction.triggered.connect(self.ftp_lst)

        self.tool = self.addToolBar('Tools')
        self.tool.setIconSize(QSize(32, 32))
        self.tool.addAction(self.refreshAction)
        self.tool.addAction(self.exitAction)


        self.FTP_tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.FTP_tree.setDisabled(True)
        self.FTP_tree.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.downloading_from_server)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.FTP_tree)

        self.model = QFileSystemModel(self)
        self.model.setRootPath('')
        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.tree.clicked.connect(self.on_treeView_clicked)
        self.tree.clicked.connect(self.uploading_files_to_server)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.tree)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def on_treeView_clicked(self, index):
        indexItem = self.model.index(index.row(), 0, index.parent())
        self.filePath = self.model.filePath(indexItem)
        if QFileInfo(self.filePath).completeSuffix() != '':
            return self.filePath
        else: 
            pass


    def disconnect_FTP_server(self):
        self.ftp.close()
        self.FTP_tree.clear()
        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.FTP_tree.setDisabled(True)



    def word_getWelcome(self):
        str1 = self.ftp.getwelcome()
        self.words = str1.split()


    def connect_FTP_server(self):
        msg = "Введите информацию о сервере"
        fieldNames = ["IP Сервера", "Логин", "Пароль"]
        title = 'FTP' 
        self.ftp_log = easygui.multpasswordbox(msg, title, fieldNames)
        try:
            self.ftp = ftplib.FTP("192.168.0.1" ,"Artem" ,"1204")
            self.ftp.encoding = 'utf-8'
            self.ftp.set_pasv(False)
        except TypeError:
            pass
        return self.ftp



    def ftp_lst(self):
        self.FTP_tree.clear()
        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.FTP_tree.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.FTP_tree.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.openMenu)
        self.FTP_tree.setDisabled(False)
        self.FTP_item1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.FTP_tree, ['..'])
        self.nlst = self.ftp.nlst()
        self.nlst_len = len(self.nlst)
        for i in self.nlst:
            j = []
            j.append(i)    
            j.append(str(self.ftp.size(i)))
            self.FTP_item1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.FTP_tree, j)
            self.FTP_item1.setFlags(self.FTP_item1.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        # self.splitter.addWidget(self.FTP_tree)
        self.file_lst = self.ftp.nlst()
        self.len_file_lst = len(self.nlst)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        # self.FTP_tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()


    def openMenu(self, position):
        self.position = position
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()

        self.delete = QtWidgets.QAction('Delete', self.menu)
        self.menu.addAction(self.delete)
        self.delete.triggered.connect(self.delete_file)

        self.new_folder_open = QtWidgets.QAction('Create a folder and open', self.menu)
        self.menu.addAction(self.new_folder_open)
        self.new_folder_open.triggered.connect(self.newfolderopen)

        self.copy_to_clipboard = QtWidgets.QAction('Copy to clipboard', self.menu)
        self.menu.addAction(self.copy_to_clipboard)
        self.copy_to_clipboard.triggered.connect(self.copytoclipboard)

        self.new_folder = QtWidgets.QAction('New folder', self.menu)
        self.menu.addAction(self.new_folder)
        self.new_folder.triggered.connect(self.newfolder)

        self.rename = QtWidgets.QAction('Rename', self.menu)
        self.rename.triggered.connect(self.rename_file)
        self.menu.addAction(self.rename)

        if self.FTP_tree.itemAt(self.position) != None:
            self.menu.exec_(self.FTP_tree.viewport().mapToGlobal(self.position))
        else:
            pass

    def copytoclipboard(self):
        a = f'ftp://{self.ftp_log[0]}{self.ftp.pwd()}/{self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0)}'
        print(pyperclip.copy(a))

    def newfolderopen(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'FTPZ',
            'Enter a new folder name:')
        a = self.FTP_tree.itemAt(self.position).text(0)
        print(a)
        if ok:
            print(ok)
            self.ftp.mkd(text)
            b = f'{self.ftp.pwd()}/{text}'
            self.ftp.cwd(b)  
        self.ftp_lst()

    def newfolder(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'FTPZ',
            'Enter a new folder name:')
        a = self.FTP_tree.itemAt(self.position).text(0)
        print(a)
        if ok:
            print(ok)
            self.ftp.mkd(text)
        self.ftp_lst()



    def rename_file(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'FTPZ',
            'Enter a new file name:')
        a = self.FTP_tree.itemAt(self.position).text(0)
        print(a)
        if ok:
            self.ftp.rename(a, text)
            print(ok)
            self.ftp_lst()

    def delete_file(self):
        self.name_file = self.FTP_tree.itemAt(self.position)
        print(self.name_file)
        self.ftp.delete(self.name_file.text(0))
        self.ftp_lst()

    def dwc(self):
        url = self.ftp.pwd()
        b = -2
        while True:
            if url[b] == '/':
                c = url[:b]
                break
            else:
                b -= 1
        if c == '':
            c = '/'
        return c


    def uploading_files_to_server(self):
        f1 = open(self.filePath, "rb")
        filename = QUrl(self.filePath).fileName() 
        self.ftp.storbinary("STOR" + filename, f1)
        f1.close()


    def downloading_from_server(self):
        b = f'{self.ftp.pwd()}/{self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0)}'
        c = QUrl(b).fileName()

        if self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0) == '..':
            self.ftp.cwd(self.dwc())
            self.ftp_lst()

        elif QFileInfo(c).completeSuffix() == '':
            self.ftp.cwd(b)  
            self.ftp_lst()

        else:
            way = easygui.diropenbox()
            host_file = os.path.join(
                way, self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0)
            )

            try:
                with open(host_file, 'wb') as local_file:
                    self.ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0), local_file.write)
            except ftplib.error_perm:
                pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.resize(640, 480)                    
    ex.show()                              
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Если иконки находятся в файле ресурсов, то к ним надо обращаться либо так (если через псевдоним): `://<name>.ico`, либо так `:/<name>.ico`, либо вместо <name> подставить полный путь к файлу

Comment: объясните пожалуйста лучше, где у вас находятся изображения: в файле ресурсов или в каталоге или ...? Что такое `:\FTP\ ` ? Что такое `FTP` ?

Comment: это папка где хранятся изображения

Comment: для чего вы поставили `:` в начале пути `:\FTP\ ` ?

Comment: потому что не оч понимаю, как это должно работать и пробывал все варианты :)

Comment: где находится папку `FTP` относительно вашего текущего каталога, из которого вы запускаете программу ?

Comment: Файл проекта находится на рабочем столе и папка ```FTP``` там же

Comment: так пробовали `self.refreshAction = QAction(QIcon('FTP/refresh.png'), 'Refresh')`

Comment: Да пробывал, не работает

Comment: покажите полную строку запуска программы, как вы ее запускаете ?

Comment: ```C:\Users\User> & C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/User/Desktop/FTP-CLIENT (2).py"``` это?

Comment: так пробовали `self.refreshAction = QAction(QIcon('../FTP/refresh.png'), 'Refresh')`

Comment: только что попробывал, не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у меня работает так:

```
import sys
import ftplib
import easygui 
import pyperclip
import os
from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, Qt                              
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QGraphicsOpacityEffect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication, QMenuBar, qApp
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileSystemModel, QHBoxLayout, QShortcut, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QMenu, QSplitter
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QRect, QFileInfo, Qt, QSize, QDir
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QKeySequence, QImage


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.splitter)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.columns = ['Name', 'Size']

        self.file = self.menuBar().addMenu('&File')
        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), '&Exit', self)
        self.exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.file.addAction(self.exitAction)

        self.server = self.menuBar().addMenu('Server')
        self.connectAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), 'Connect server', self)
        self.connectAction.setStatusTip('Connect server')
        self.connectAction.triggered.connect(self.connect_FTP_server)
        self.connectAction.triggered.connect(self.ftp_lst)
        self.server.addAction(self.connectAction)

        self.disconnectAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), 'Disconnect server', self)
        self.disconnectAction.setStatusTip('Disconnect server')
        self.disconnectAction.triggered.connect(self.disconnect_FTP_server)
        self.server.addAction(self.disconnectAction)

        self.updateAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), 'Update list file', self)
        self.updateShortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence("F5"), self)
        self.updateShortcut.activated.connect(self.ftp_lst)
        self.updateAction.setStatusTip('Update list file')
        self.updateAction.triggered.connect(self.ftp_lst)
        self.server.addAction(self.updateAction)


#        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon(':\FTP\disconnect.png'), 'Exit')
        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon('c:/Users/User/Desktop/FTP/im.png'), 'Exit')        

        self.exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.disconnect_FTP_server)

#        self.refreshAction = QAction(QIcon(':\FTP\refresh.png'), 'Refresh')
        self.refreshAction = QAction(QIcon('c:/Users/User/Desktop/FTP/Ok.png'), 'Refresh')


        self.refreshAction.setShortcut('F5')
        self.refreshAction.triggered.connect(self.ftp_lst)
        self.tool = self.addToolBar('Tools')
        self.tool.setIconSize(QSize(32, 32))
        self.tool.addAction(self.refreshAction)
        self.tool.addAction(self.exitAction)


        self.FTP_tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.FTP_tree.setDisabled(True)
        self.FTP_tree.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.downloading_from_server)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.FTP_tree)

        self.model = QFileSystemModel(self)
        self.model.setRootPath('')
        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.tree.clicked.connect(self.on_treeView_clicked)
        self.tree.clicked.connect(self.uploading_files_to_server)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.tree)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def on_treeView_clicked(self, index):
        indexItem = self.model.index(index.row(), 0, index.parent())
        self.filePath = self.model.filePath(indexItem)
        if QFileInfo(self.filePath).completeSuffix() != '':
            return self.filePath
        else: 
            pass


    def disconnect_FTP_server(self):
        self.ftp.close()
        self.FTP_tree.clear()
        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.FTP_tree.setDisabled(True)



    def word_getWelcome(self):
        str1 = self.ftp.getwelcome()
        self.words = str1.split()


    def connect_FTP_server(self):
        msg = "Введите информацию о сервере"
        fieldNames = ["IP Сервера", "Логин", "Пароль"]
        title = 'FTP' 
        self.ftp_log = easygui.multpasswordbox(msg, title, fieldNames)
        try:
            self.ftp = ftplib.FTP("192.168.0.1" ,"Artem" ,"1204")
            self.ftp.encoding = 'utf-8'
            self.ftp.set_pasv(False)
        except TypeError:
            pass
        return self.ftp



    def ftp_lst(self):
        self.FTP_tree.clear()
        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.FTP_tree.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.FTP_tree.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.openMenu)
        self.FTP_tree.setDisabled(False)
        self.FTP_item1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.FTP_tree, ['..'])
        self.nlst = self.ftp.nlst()
        self.nlst_len = len(self.nlst)
        for i in self.nlst:
            j = []
            j.append(i)    
            j.append(str(self.ftp.size(i)))
            self.FTP_item1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.FTP_tree, j)
            self.FTP_item1.setFlags(self.FTP_item1.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        # self.splitter.addWidget(self.FTP_tree)
        self.file_lst = self.ftp.nlst()
        self.len_file_lst = len(self.nlst)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        # self.FTP_tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()


    def openMenu(self, position):
        self.position = position
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()

        self.delete = QtWidgets.QAction('Delete', self.menu)
        self.menu.addAction(self.delete)
        self.delete.triggered.connect(self.delete_file)

        self.new_folder_open = QtWidgets.QAction('Create a folder and open', self.menu)
        self.menu.addAction(self.new_folder_open)
        self.new_folder_open.triggered.connect(self.newfolderopen)

        self.copy_to_clipboard = QtWidgets.QAction('Copy to clipboard', self.menu)
        self.menu.addAction(self.copy_to_clipboard)
        self.copy_to_clipboard.triggered.connect(self.copytoclipboard)

        self.new_folder = QtWidgets.QAction('New folder', self.menu)
        self.menu.addAction(self.new_folder)
        self.new_folder.triggered.connect(self.newfolder)

        self.rename = QtWidgets.QAction('Rename', self.menu)
        self.rename.triggered.connect(self.rename_file)
        self.menu.addAction(self.rename)

        if self.FTP_tree.itemAt(self.position) != None:
            self.menu.exec_(self.FTP_tree.viewport().mapToGlobal(self.position))
        else:
            pass

    def copytoclipboard(self):
        a = f'ftp://{self.ftp_log[0]}{self.ftp.pwd()}/{self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0)}'
        print(pyperclip.copy(a))

    def newfolderopen(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'FTPZ',
            'Enter a new folder name:')
        a = self.FTP_tree.itemAt(self.position).text(0)
        print(a)
        if ok:
            print(ok)
            self.ftp.mkd(text)
            b = f'{self.ftp.pwd()}/{text}'
            self.ftp.cwd(b)  
        self.ftp_lst()

    def newfolder(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'FTPZ',
            'Enter a new folder name:')
        a = self.FTP_tree.itemAt(self.position).text(0)
        print(a)
        if ok:
            print(ok)
            self.ftp.mkd(text)
        self.ftp_lst()



    def rename_file(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'FTPZ',
            'Enter a new file name:')
        a = self.FTP_tree.itemAt(self.position).text(0)
        print(a)
        if ok:
            self.ftp.rename(a, text)
            print(ok)
            self.ftp_lst()

    def delete_file(self):
        self.name_file = self.FTP_tree.itemAt(self.position)
        print(self.name_file)
        self.ftp.delete(self.name_file.text(0))
        self.ftp_lst()

    def dwc(self):
        url = self.ftp.pwd()
        b = -2
        while True:
            if url[b] == '/':
                c = url[:b]
                break
            else:
                b -= 1
        if c == '':
            c = '/'
        return c


    def uploading_files_to_server(self):
        f1 = open(self.filePath, "rb")
        filename = QUrl(self.filePath).fileName() 
        self.ftp.storbinary("STOR" + filename, f1)
        f1.close()


    def downloading_from_server(self):
        b = f'{self.ftp.pwd()}/{self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0)}'
        c = QUrl(b).fileName()

        if self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0) == '..':
            self.ftp.cwd(self.dwc())
            self.ftp_lst()

        elif QFileInfo(c).completeSuffix() == '':
            self.ftp.cwd(b)  
            self.ftp_lst()

        else:
            way = easygui.diropenbox()
            host_file = os.path.join(
                way, self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0)
            )

            try:
                with open(host_file, 'wb') as local_file:
                    self.ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0), local_file.write)
            except ftplib.error_perm:
                pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.resize(640, 480)                    
    ex.show()                              
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]